# react "next start" in existing google cloud static bucket

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have a google cloud static bucket serving my static site. It works great. Now I want to add a folder into that bucket that will run a react app. I want to use "next start" command, since i've compiled the js accordingly and assume it will build dependencies.

WHAT DO I DO?

I would normally make a daemon file to sustain npm run, ect. But with google cloud, what on earth do i do. I can't cd into the bucket to run commands. utterly confused.

please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the buckets for static web pages what people usually do is to first deploy locally (in Cloud Shell, for example) and then upload all the files into the bucket.

There are some Medium blogs about how to do it in [React](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/deploy-your-static-react-application-on-google-cloud-platform-bc8afb9b9b6) or in [Next.js](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-host-a-next-js-static-website-with-gcp-cloud-storage-2bc481b9cef8). Anything that needs more interactions it would be better to handle it through [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine) or [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run). And if the app with your static site are not related I would advise to build them in a different bucket.

If you want more information about the static website there is also official documentation about [it](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#console_1) with some [examples and tips](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website).